# Отладка с помощью phpStorm и xDebug на хостинге Beget

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm, xdebug

Как настроить отладчик xDebug с phpStorm, если сайт размещён не на виртуальном сервере, а на shared-хостинге? Возможно ли это в принципе? Если нет, существует ли такая возможность для хостинга Beget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае - нет, далеко не все shared-хостинги позволяют запускать xDebug и проводить отладку. К счастью, Beget является исключением.

В принципе, в разделе справки есть [инструкция](https://beget.com/ru/articles/xdebug). Однако, она не лишена неточностей, что вызывает проблемы при настройке. Ниже приведена последовательность подключения шаг за шагом, с указанием на отличия от официальной документации.

Для работы xDebug PHP должен работать в режиме CGI. Для переключения режима работы PHP откройте раздел [Сайты](https://cp.beget.com/sites) панели управления, нажмите на кнопку "PHP" напротив нужного домена и поставьте галочку "Режим CGI". На переключение режима работы может потребоваться до 15 минут.

*Здесь хостер страхуется, на самом деле переключение происходит довольно бысто - за несколько секунд.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее надо создать несколько файлов, если их нет, а для этого (а, главное, для отладки позже) нужно подключиться к Beget по ssh. Работающая инструкция находится [здесь](https://beget.com/ru/articles/ssh_windows), переписывать её сюда не вижу смысла.

В корне сайта должен находиться каталог `cgi-bin`, а в нём - файл php.ini. Если каталог cgi-bin и/или файл php.ini отсутствуют, их нужно создать. В запущенном вами окне ssh введите команды:

```
account@server:~/site.com/public_html [0] $ mkdir cgi-bin
account@server:~/site.com/public_html [0] $ php5.6 --ini | head -n2
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/cgi/5.6
    Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/cgi/5.6/php.ini
account@server:~/site.com/public_html [0] $ cp /etc/php/cgi/5.6/php.ini cgi-bin
account@server:~/site.com/public_html [0] $
```

В примере копируется файл для php5.6.

*Далее в основной инструкции по xDebug идут рекомендации по поводу файла php.ini, которые не работают для php7.1. На самом деле надо сделать следующее.*

Для включения расширения xDebug нужно добавить следующие строки в конец файла cgi-bin/php.ini:

```
zend_extension = /home/i/infomi37/vc.mint-studio.org/public_html/cgi-bin/xdebug-2.5.5/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=8014
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

где `/home/i/....` - путь к вашему сайту на сервере Beget.

Потом нужно [скачать c официального сайта](https://xdebug.org/download.php) версию xDebug под выбранную вами версию php. Обратите внимание, что последняя версия 2.6.0 поддерживает только php7.

Разархивируйте файл xdebug-2.5.5.tgz (это можно сделать на локакльном компьютере) и поместите папку `xdebug-2.5.5` и файл `package.xml` в папку `/cgi-bin` в корне вашего сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убедитесь, что по пути, указанному в `zend_extension` выше, присутствует `xdebug.so`.

На этом неточности в упомянутой инструкции по xDebug заканчиваются, и ею вполне можно пользоваться начиная с раздела `Настройка работы IDE PhpStorm с xDebug`.

И да, не забывайте запускать ssh с туннелем во время отладки!